# rte_mbuf in dpdk 18.08 doesnt have struct rte_pktmbuf pkt

Tags: c, linux, dpdk

I am getting the below compilation error after upgrading to  dpdk 18.08 version.

```
error: ‘struct rte_mbuf’ has no member named ‘pkt’
  m->pkt.data = ((char*)m->pkt.data - (BTG_IP_VHL_HL(ip->version_ihl) << 2));
   ^
```

As per the documentation rte_mbuf struct no longer has  packet message buffer struct rte_pktmbuf pkt which inturn holds void* data which contains start address of data in segment buffer.

```
struct rte_mbuf {
.
.
.
union {
        struct rte_ctrlmbuf ctrl;
        struct rte_pktmbuf pkt;
    };
}
struct rte_pktmbuf {
    /* valid for any segment */
    struct rte_mbuf *next; 
    void* data;  /**< Start address of data in segment buffer. */
```

Please let me know which other field of rte_mbuf struct can be used with dpdk 18.08 version which means start address of data in the packet message buffer so as to resolve this compilation error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: You have a nameless-union?  What's inside the `...` ? Are there some `;` missing?

Comment: Please add the previous version against which the compilation was working

Comment: Previous DPDK version was 1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, t)` macro.

> A macro that points to the start of the data in the mbuf.
>
> The returned pointer is cast to type t. Before using this function, the user must ensure that the first segment is large enough to accommodate its data.

Source: [DPDK API](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__mbuf_8h.html#a2a8b10263496c7b580e9d0c7f2a1f073)

#### Update:

To prepend a packet buffer with some data, there is a dedicated function for that: `rte_pktmbuf_prepend()` (and here is [DPDK documentation](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__mbuf_8h.html#aadf5bef4ceb0b76dfafff0895f285ab0))

It's hard to be 100% sure without the context of your old code, but it looks like this fragment must be rewritten to:

```
rte_pktmbuf_prepend(m,
        BTG_IP_VHL_HL(ip->version_ihl) << 2);
```

Comment: Thanks. So can I replace the above piece of code with:                                                                                                                                                                                                           rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, void *) = (rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, void *) -  (BTG_IP_VH                                                                                       L_HL(ip->version_ihl) << 2));                                                                                                               I hope this should work.

Comment: But this gives compilation error.                                                        error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
         rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, void *) = (rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, void *) - (BTG_IP_VH L_HL(ip->version_ihl) << 2));Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: @user3509719 I've updated the answer with `rte_pktmbuf_prepend()`.

Comment: Thanks.After replacing with rte_pktmbuf_prepend it worked.Further I used rte_pktmbuf_append(m,hlen) in place of   m->pkt.data = ((char*)m->pkt.data + hlen);